# Rails nested new view is being routed to show for some reason?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Running Rails 3.2.1, I have the following routes:

```
resources :photos, :path_names => { :new => 'upload' } do
  resources :votes
end
```

For some reason if I browse to `photos/1/votes/new` I'm getting

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in VotesController#show
Couldn't find Vote with id=new
```

Why would Rails be routing `votes/new` to the show action? Has anyone ever encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Facepalm!

I didn't realize the `:path_names` option would apply to nested resources as well -- the Votes model was looking for the new action at `votes/upload` instead of `votes/new`.

I changed the routes as follows and all is well:

```
resources :photos do
  collection do
    get 'upload' => 'photos#new'
  end
  resources :votes
end
```